How to filter out staled events using XLib?
Inside a function I want to make a request to the X server (by calling some XLib function) and wait for the reply. But the reply may never happen under certain circumstances, for example, if a property I am trying to read has been destroyed due to the user closed a window or whatever else. So, to avoid possible infinite block, I only want to wait for a specific event for a certain amount of time, and, if the event has not been arrived within this time, I am just not interested in it anymore. To set an event timeout I use the XSyncCreateAlarm() function from the X Synchronization Extension Protocol. The idea is the following this:
void foo()
{
    make_request_to_x_server();

    // Set timeout and wait for response...
    while (true)
    {
        ::XEvent event{};
        ::XNextEvent(display, &event);
        if (/* event matches some predicate */)
        {
            // Do something
            break;
        }
        else if (/* timeout */)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

Unfortunately, this approach has a significant drawback - the event I am waiting for may be delayed for any reasons and not appear within the timeout, the function will return then, but the next time foo() is called this stale event may arrive suddenly and trigger the if() block falsely, if the predicate is still satisfied. Getting the SERVERTIME counter before calling make_request_to_x_server() and then checking if an event timestamp exceeds this time does not seem to be a reliable solution - there will still be a time window between the function call and executing the if() block, and the stale event may occur right withing this time window. The serial field of XEvent structure also seems to be useless, it just represents the order in which events were generated by the server, and this order may not even match the order of the related requests, as far as I know.
Are there any reliable options for dealing with such issues? How to filter out such "outdated" events?

any particular reason why you're not using Xcb and are instead programming against XLib? Xcb was created in particular to deal with situations such as yours. And for that matter these days Xlib is actually a wrapper around Xcb.

@datenwolf, well, I may be stupid, but I can't find a good documentation for xcb. XLib, on the other hand, although it is very ancient and complicated, is really well documented. And toolkits like GTK/QT are too monstrous for my use case.
